# Will it be possible to compare two arbitrary functions with std::any in C++17?

Tags: c++, c++17, stdany

I think it is a big limitation of how C++ handles function pointers and std::function, that it is currently impossible to compare two arbitrary functions of different type in an elegant way.

I am now wondering if C++17 will change that with the introduction of `std::any`

```
void foo(int a) {}
int bar(float b) {}

void main()
{
    std::any oneFoo = std::make_any(foo);
    std::any oneBar = std::make_any(bar);
    std::any anotherFoo = std::make_any(foo);

    bool shouldBeFalse = (oneBar == oneFoo);
    bool shouldBeTrue = (oneFoo == anotherFoo);
}
```

Is this gonna behave the way I expect it ?

Comment: [Any reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) would make it clear that it doesn't have comparison operators. That would limit what you can put into it more than necessary.

Comment: So even with C++17 we would still have no elegant cross platform way to solve this problem ? Damn

Comment: Function objects can't even be compared like that themselves normally, let alone when type-erased.

Comment: Well, there's always `std::function`'s [`target()` member function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/target). Other than that, be aware that function identity is kind of a fuzzy concept in C++.

Comment: @ComicSansMS The concept I'm interested in is identity as in same adress, but I read that the way function pointers are implemented in C++ you don't actually have a reliable way to check for that

Comment: So do you want any `int(int)` to match any other `int(int)`?

Comment: @N0vember Well, you can do that [as long as they have the same type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12898227/comparing-function-pointers). If they don't have the same type you kind of already know the answer beforehand, they're just not equal.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing function pointers is easy. You are not even required to use `C++17`, but it helps shorten the code :

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int a) {}
int bar(float b) { return 0; }

template <class A, class B> bool pointer_equals(A *a, B *b) {
  if
    constexpr(std::is_same<A, B>::value) { return a == b; }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}

int main(int, char *[]) {
  std::cout << "Should be false: " << pointer_equals(foo, bar) << "\n"
            << "Should be true: " << pointer_equals(foo, foo) << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

The problem is : *functions* are just one kind of *callable*, and there is a lot of different possible callables in `C++`. Equality by pointer is kind of weak from a functional standpoint.

Comment: Well, for two arbitrary functions it is undecidable whether they compute the same thing, so what more would you hope for?