# Three-way comparison of pointer to functions fails

Tags: c++, c++20, spaceship-operator

Why can't I compare pointers to functions with GCC trunk?

```
using f_t = int(*)(int);
f_t a { nullptr }, b { nullptr };
auto c = a <=> b;

int main (){}
```

gives

```
a.cpp:4:13: error: invalid operands of types ‘f_t’ {aka ‘int (*)(int)’} and ‘f_t’ {aka ‘int (*)(int)’} to binary ‘operator<=>’
    4 | auto c = (a <=> b) == 0;
      |           ~ ^~~ ~
      |           |     |
      |           |     f_t {aka int (*)(int)}
      |           f_t {aka int (*)(int)}
```

Comment: What are you expecting `<=>` to return when they're not equal? The address of functions is even less useful than normal addresses (varying between compilations, and can even vary from run to run if one function comes from a separate DLL/shared object loaded with ASLR); there's nothing useful to be gained from determining which is "lesser" and which is "greater". [Earlier C++ specs only defined `==`/`!=` for function pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12898227/364696); I wouldn't expect them to have expanded it since.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086372/how-to-compare-pointers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of using normal relational operators on function pointers is [unspecified if the pointers are unequal](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.rel#4). You can compare pointers to objects (but only meaningfully if they're pointers into the same array or structure), but relating function pointers isn't really viable.

Rather than taking the sometimes-unspecified route, [C++20 simply forbids using `<=>` for non-object pointers](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.spaceship#8).

You can test for equality between such pointers, but not their relative ordering. If you absolutely need to do this for some reason, you can cast the pointers to `void*`s and use `std::less<>` for such comparisons.

Comment: Is comparison on `void*`s even defined?

Comment: Ok but `auto d = a < b;` does compile though.

Comment: @Barry: It is for `std::less` when applied to pointers. That is, if converting a function pointer to a `void*` is a well-defined operation (which is not actually a requirement), then `std::less` must provide a well-defined total order of such pointers.